# Python/OpenCV: event.pos() do not correspond to the correct clicked values

Tags: python, opencv, coordinates

We are using Python 3.6 and OpenCV.

We are trying to get the coordinates (x,y) from two points from a presented image.

We have `setFrame`  function to show the image as below:

```
def setFrame(self):

        global video

        num = self.frame_scrollBar.value()
        self.video_frame.setScaledContents(True); #QLabel will resize itself to the size of pixmap/image and scroll-bar will get visible.
        cvRGBImg = cv2.cvtColor(video[num-1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #Convert opencv RGB image to QImage
        qimg = QtGui.QImage(cvRGBImg.data,cvRGBImg.shape[1], cvRGBImg.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        qpm = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qimg)
        self.video_frame.setPixmap(qpm)
```

Also, we have `getPos` function in order to get the (x,y) coordinates:

```
def getPos(self, event):

        global setPoint
        global coords
        global video

        if setPoint == True:
            x = event.pos().x()
            y = event.pos().y()

            coords.append((x,y))
            cv2.circle(video[int(self.frame_3.text())-1],(x,y),3,(0,0,255),-1)
            self.setFrame()
            if len(coords)==2:
                setPoint = False
                print (coords[0])
                print (coords[1])
                self.message()
```

The problem is that when we click to a point on the presented image, the coordinates are not correct. E.g. We click to a point a we see the circle above this point and the (x,y) do not correspond to the point that we clicked.

We also tried to get the coordinates using `pygame` but still no luck.

Do we have to perform some kind of transformation? In case we do not use `self.video_frame.setScaledContents(True)` then the presented image is showed displaced in the `QPixmap`.
Can you please help us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution.

The problem is that the `QLabel` size did not correspond to the presented image size.

`QLabel` size is 491x371 and the image size is 512x512. So we have to transform the clicked coordinates like:

```
x = event.pos().x()
x = int(x*(512/491)) # coordinates/pixels must be integers
y = event.pos().y()
y = int(y*(512/371))
```

So now the command `cv2.circle(video[int(self.frame_3.text())-1],(x,y),3,(0,0,255),-1)` designs the circle in the correct position.